# Notify parent that there was a change on its child

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm making a nested form with dynamic validation on Angular 2. I have a parent (`finalizaNegociacaoComponent`) which holds the nested forms and other properties and, there's the component `dadosTitular` which **is** the nested form. Inside my nested form I have a checkbox that calls a function, this function change some inputs in my form. I want to know how I let the parent `finalizaNegociacaoComponent` realize that there were a change on the form.

This is the function that the checkbox call (this is inside `dadosTitularComponent`:

```
handleType(isJuridica: boolean, i:number): void {
  let array = <FormArray> this.formDadosBancarios.get('dados_titular');
  let cpf = array.at(0).get("cpf");
  let cnpj = array.at(0).get('cnpj');
  let data_nasc = array.at(0).get('data_nasc');
  const cpfCtrl = this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular',0,'cpf']);
  const cnpjCtrl = this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular',0, 'cnpj']);
  const data_nascCtrl = this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular',0,'data_nasc']);
  const reqValidators: ValidatorFn[] = [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.cpf_REGEXP)];
  if (isJuridica) {
    cpfCtrl.setValidators(null);
    data_nascCtrl.setValidators(null);
    cnpjCtrl.setValidators(reqValidators);
  }else{
    cpfCtrl.setValidators(reqValidators);
    data_nascCtrl.setValidators(reqValidators)
    cnpjCtrl.setValidators(null);
  }
  cpfCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
  data_nascCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
  cnpjCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

So, this function set and remove validators from some inputs, the problem is that `finalizaNegociacaoComponent`never "realize it". How can I update it? I guess it has something with ngOnchages but I'm still very lost :(. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous ways you can notify a parent component of a change in a child component.  One way for example, in your child component `dadosTitularComponent` you could implement an `Output` parameter that emits an updated value when the model changes:

```
@Output() modelChanged = new EventEmitter();
```

Then you can have the event emitter emit a value from the `handleType` function your checkbox calls with:

```
this.modelChanged.emit(someValue);
```

The `someValue` will be emitted through the Output variable `modelChanged` to the parent.

The parent component could listen for the `modelChanged` event with

```
<app-dadosTitularComponent (modelChanged)="someFunction($event)"></app-dadosTitularComponent>
```

Where `someFunction` is a function in the parent that can act on the changed model.

Hope that helps.

---

`ngOnChanges` is great for monitoring changes to Input properties on your child component, but that is monitoring changes sent from the parent into the child and not what you are wanting.  You would set it up on your `@Input()` properties like this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes['myInput'].currentValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tyler, I just didint understand what is `somevalue` cause as you can see I'm not returning a single value to the parent component. What I return are some changes on some of my inputs. Also, the this.modelChanged.emit(someValue);`` will be at the end of the `handletype`?

Comment: `someValue` can be anything.  It can be your entire model if you want, not just a single value.  Yes, I would put the `this.modelChanged.emit(...)` at the end of `handleType`.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, you really helped me out :)

Comment: Glad I could help.